# HTML5 manifest and chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, manifest, rich-internet-application

I am seeing this error in my console for chrome.

```
Application Cache Error event: Failed to commit new cache to storage, would exceed quota
```

it means what it seems to mean right?  That my app is trying to cache too much data?

Is there anything that can be done about it?

Same site works in FF no issues.

Comment: This may help: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=098d42a41aacdc6d&hl=en

Comment: @bryan I am embarrassed to admit that my css guy checked in a 4mb background image that i didnt see.  thatll do it.  should i just delete the post?

Comment: Ha! After I posted my comment, I realized that it isn't exactly reasonable to ask your users to issue commands to alter Chrome's cache limit. My next thought was, "What the heck is this guy trying to serve that exceeds the limit?" A 4mb image definitely explains it. I'd leave the post in case somebody else runs into this.

Comment: @bryan,  of course now I am just getting "Application Cache Error event: Failed to commit new cache to storage" with no explanation....:(

Comment: This may be a silly question, but did you clear your cache? Does this happen to other machines that haven't viewed the app in Chrome?

Comment: @bryan, yes i have tried.  The app is online, but i didn't want to post the url because i didnt want that interpreted as an underhanded way to get traffic.  I could post the url though....

Comment: I'm pretty sure you and I are the only ones reading this thread, and I'm not buying whatever you're selling, so post away!

Comment: Each browser has it's own individual size limit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you just want to **change the size of your cache**, start chrome with "--disk-cache-size=N".

If you want to see whats in your cache, just type **about:cache** or **about:appcache-internals** in the Omnibar.

For a reference file: [DOMApplicationCache Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/DataManagement/Reference/DOMApplicationCacheClassReference/DOMApplicationCache/DOMApplicationCache.html) or google "A Beginner's Guide to Using the Application Cache" (I may not post more links, I'm sorry)

Comment: +1 The second URI (`about:appcache-internals`) allows the user to clear out various cache items. Doing this fixed MobileMe to start working again with Chrome.

Answer (score 9):

The error can also occur when your system drive is running low on disk space, so freeing up disk space can resolve this in this situation.

Comment: clearing the recycle bin fixed the similar issue on our website (800mb free disk space before and 5gb after)

Comment: Glad that it helped. I encountered the same thing; in my case my SSD on C drive was nearly full. Definitely time for a bigger SSD! :)